# Selecting Excel range throwing 1004 error in MS Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a procedure that receives a file name and opens the file to copy a range of data into an Access database.

It works if I run it one file at a time.

When I pass it a second file it throws

> Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed.

If I close and start again it is fine.

I have read a other questions about this error and tried different things.

I validated there isn't anything different in any of the files. I ran it on at least 15 files one at a time and one-by-one they run fine. I tried calling the range in different ways, using Select instead of range, etc.

I tried it in both Access 2010 and Access 2016.

The error happens right after the >>> PROBLEM HERE line below.

```
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim mysheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(vfilepath & "\" & vfilename)
appExcel.Visible = True
    
With appExcel

    With appExcel.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

        ' >>> PROBLEM HERE
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2", Range("N2").End(xlDown)).Select

        Selection.Copy
    End With

    DoCmd.OpenTable "tblExcelImport_Main", acViewNormal
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPasteAppend
    DoCmd.Close acTable, "tblExcelImport_Main", acSaveYes

    myWorkbook.Close
    appExcel.Quit
    Set appExcel = Nothing
    Set myWorkbook = Nothing
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    
End With
End If
```

I need to loop through each file until finished (about 25 files - none are huge).

Comment: I don't see an opening 'IF' statement which may cause problems, but I think the main issue is you need to iterate over each file. I think a Do While loop might be what you are after. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement

Answer (score 4):

Many issues here:

1. Unnecessary `Select`'s and `Activate`'s
2. Unqualified `Worksheets` reference. Access doesn't know about `Worksheets`, that will error
3. Unqualified `Range`  reference.  Access doesn't know about `Range`, that will error
4. While you have coded `With` blocks, you are not actually using them
5. Excel.Application object doesn't have a Worksheets collection
6. Clean up of objects in wrong order

If this code were written in Excel VBA, unqualified `Worksheets(...` would imply `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(...`, and unqualified `Range(...` would imply `ActiveSheet.Range(...`

Since this code is written in Access VBA, VBA can't resolve those implicit references.

So, all Excel objects and methods must be fully qualified back to the Excel Application object `appExcel`

Refactored:

```
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(vfilepath & "\" & vfilename)

'...

Set mysheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With mysheet 
    .Range("B2", .Range("N2").End(xlDown)).Copy
End With

'....

Set mysheet = Nothing
myWorkbook.Close
Set myWorkbook = Nothing
appExcel.Quit
Set appExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Don't you need `appExcel` before `myWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` when setting `mysheet`?

Comment: @Dan No, because of the `Set myWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(...` `myWorkbook` is already correctly assigned.

Comment: Ahhh yes my bad, didn't look at the upper part of the code :)

Comment: seems to work now - I guess I just go myself so lost in trying to fix it that I tried everything and ended up with a bunch of garbage.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When using `With` you need to precede with a period / Full Stop `.`

Something like this (I cleaned up the select too)

```
With appExcel
    .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2", .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N2").End(xlDown)).Copy
End With
```

Not really sure why you had the second `With` in there.

Comment: the second with was really a shot in the dark attempt at anything :(  Didn't originally have it there.  Will try this and let you know.  TX

Comment: To be honest I think Chris’s answer may be better for you but see if this works